# Changing activity indicator color to black

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm trying to change my activity indicator to a custom color like black. However it does not seem to apply at all and has the standard white color still.

What i've done is creating a UIView and and added a activity indicator as a subView and then added this to the tableFooterView.

How can I change the activity indicator color?

ViewDidLoad:

```
    let footerView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 40))
    footerView.backgroundColor = UIColor(rgba: "#f6f7f9")
    var actInd: UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView()
    actInd.color = UIColor.blackColor()
    actInd.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2-10, 0.0, 20.0, 20.0);

    actInd.activityIndicatorViewStyle =
        UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.WhiteLarge
    footerView.addSubview(actInd)
    actInd.startAnimating()
    self.tableVIew.tableFooterView = footerView
```

Comment: You actually did it right using the color property. Just set the indicator style before adding color.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

You need to set the color after you set the activity indicator style. It seems that setting the `activityIndicatorViewStyle` resets the color for the `activityIndicator`

So just do this:

```
// .... 

activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.whiteLarge
activityIndicator.color = .black
footerView.addSubview(activityIndicator)
activityIndicator.startAnimating()
self.tableView.tableFooterView = footerView
```

This should work just fine.

Answer (score 14):

The documentation states

> If you set a color for an activity indicator, it **overrides** the color
>   provided by the activityIndicatorViewStyle property.

So you have to set the `activityIndicatorViewStyle` first and then set the color.

Correct:

```
actInd.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.WhiteLarge
actInd.color = UIColor.blackColor()
```

Wrong:

```
actInd.color = UIColor.blackColor()
actInd.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.WhiteLarge
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is an extension for Swift 4 that makes it easy to color the indicator.

```
import UIKit

extension UIActivityIndicatorView {
    func assignColor(_ color: UIColor) {
        activityIndicatorViewStyle = .whiteLarge
        self.color = color
    }
}
```

You call it like this:

```
activityIndicator.assignColor(.black)
```

Here is this code in action, with a random timer to change colors:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3 version**

In main class `ViewController` add activityIndicator:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {

let activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.whiteLarge)
```

Then in `viewDidLoad()`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

activityIndicator.color = UIColor.black
activityIndicator.center = CGPoint(x: view.bounds.size.width/2, y: view.bounds.size.height/2)
view.addSubview(activityIndicator)
activityIndicator.startAnimating()
```

To remove activityIndicator:

```
activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change your color after you set the indicator style. Everything else looks fine for me.